# Is my rounding formula off?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using the below script to take numbers from my table and round them based on the value. If the number is above 15, I want the value to round off to one decimal place. If the number is below 15, I want the value to round off to three decimal places. The formula is working on numbers above 15, but will not place a ".0" next to whole values. I suspect that Access will not do this. Am I right? If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

```
SELECT Tbl_Formulas.QtyPer
     , Round([QtyPer],IIf([QtyPer]<=15,3,1)) AS Expr1
FROM Tbl_Formulas;
```

Comment: There's a difference between presentation and value.  `.0` is presentation. 
Since `.0` is an insignificant value; it is not presented normally.   If you want the `.0` to show, you need to use a format mask to present the value how you want it displayed. For more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj720239.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this, but for someone who isn't that great at writing SQL statements, I'm a little lost on this. I used statements as if I were in excel to write the expressions. Then I hit SQL and copied the statement for this post. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: take a look at this: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/format.php  I think what you want is: `FORMAT(Round([QtyPer],IIf([QtyPer]<=15,3,1)), "#,##0.000")  but round will change the value; but format will change how it's presented.  it will always show 3 decimals ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Format to display .0 or .000 even for integer values:

```
SELECT 
    Tbl_Formulas.QtyPer,
    Format([QtyPer], IIf([QtyPer]<=15, "0.000", "0.0")) AS Expr1
FROM Tbl_Formulas;
```

Comment: I was so close to figuring this out thanks to Qbert. I figured out how to format all numbers one way and was working out the IIF statement to separate them. Thank you Gustav!